# create a text file using an input as part of the name

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, vba, vbscript

I need to create an app/script that works on windows with the following functionality:

- asks two inputs to the user;
- create a csv/txt file using one of the inputs( the first input) as part of the file name and save it to a specific folder;
- calls an application after the file is created.

my first concern is what would be the best method? I was considering VB or VBS but I have seen some c++ demos online. I am more comfortable with C# but would rather not have to "install" any exe file on the location because the application will run in a server.

Comment: If it runs at a server how do you want to ask for user input?

Comment: @TimSchmelter _ I don't think he means a server in that sense, I'm guessing rather a 'central machine' with a network share containing the exe

Comment: What have you tried? If I understood you correct it's very simple. You need just to do a regular "Write to file" action with creating it. Reading the location of the file, and streaming the last part of string as a parameter you will get the name with the extension and be able to write in your database.

Comment: @TimSchmelter_ It will run in a "server" type machine, it does not have a server functionality but serves as a machine everyone in my department use for this specific task.

Comment: @Mike_ Quite like that, the difference is I will need to create the file using the first input( account nº)as part of the filename. ex: 123456.csv, then run a program which will use this file, that will always be created on the same folder, in order to complete the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in VBS, use something like this:

```
dim firstInput, secondInput, folderPath, application
dim fso, myFileD
dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

folderPath = "C:\dummyFolder"
''extra "" for whitespace in path
application = """c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"""

firstInput = InputBox("Enter first input")
secondInput = InputBox("Enter second input")

Set myFile = fso.CreateTextFile(folderPath & firstInput & ".txt", True)
myFile.WriteLine(secondInput)
myFile.Close

objShell.Run(application)
```

Comment: I got it to create the file and to load the app, but when the app opens, it crashes with this error:
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: 25DVSU0T4NPA1MQDAWWVUAS1FLBFGLVC
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 504f7dd1
  Problem Signature 04: Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling
  Problem Signature 05: 4.1.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4c18e2c9
  Problem Signature 07: 15b
  Problem Signature 08: 12
  Problem Signature 09: IOIBMURHYNRXKW0ZXKYRVFN0BOYYUFOW

Comment: OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: fb87
  Additional Information 2: fb8760c1a1f17918db2b8928bab62600
  Additional Information 3: 1dbb
  Additional Information 4: 1dbb00f849b5765a1b33345ee77d0bd8

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Comment: When I try to run the app with a double click, it runs smoothily. I am running the script on the same machine as the app.